# Bash script outputs unexpected directory display - why?

Tags: bash, ubuntu

The following outputs the directory display for the tmp directory.
Why, and how to stop it.

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /tmp
echo '*' >zzz
cat zzz
IFS='' read  something <zzz
echo ${something}
```

Comment: `something=*` `echo ${something}` causes it to be expanded to the contents of the current directory. If you don't want it to expand, enclose the variable expansion in quotation marks e.g. `echo "$something"`.

Comment: If you fed this script to [shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net), then it would have shown `(info): Double quote to prevent globbing and word splitting.` for the echo line

Comment: I haven't done any BASH in years and forgot about using double quotes. Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

Quote your expansions.

```
echo "${something}"
```

See [Parameter Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html), [Word Splitting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Word-Splitting) and [Filename Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Filename-Expansion).

> The shell scans the results of parameter expansion, command
> substitution, and arithmetic expansion that did not occur within
> double quotes for word splitting.

Comment: Please refrain from answering common FAQs. Instead, vote to close as a duplicate.